# How to properly handle css-files by mini-css-extract-plugin in webpack 4?

Tags: webpack-4, mini-css-extract-plugin

There is a simple config for webpack 4

```js
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist',
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: '/node_modules/'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader'
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

CSS-file is imported to the entry point (index.js), it is necessary to output it in the production build to a separate CSS-file (using mini-css-extract-plugin, want to try exactly this plugin, not other methods). But an error occurs:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoqTW.png

Here is full file structure
https://github.com/DazzRune/webpack4test

Answer (score 0):

Everything works quite fine, webpack is compiling without any errors. Try to do `npm install`, as you have all necessary loaders to do the task.

Comment: I tried to install again, then `npm run build` and got the same error like on my screenshot.

Comment: the error says that you don't have appropriate loader to handle css file, while in your config you have it. Besides on my machine compilation succeeded without any error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
{
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    options: {
                        publicPath: (resourcePath, context) => {
                            return path.relative(path.dirname(resourcePath), context) + '/';
                        }
                    }
                },
                'css-loader'
            ]
            }
```

and

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css",
            ignoreOrder: false
        })
```

It is working with me
All credit to this [guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzdEpgONurw)!